# Setting a button to it's highlighted color state?

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine

Is there a way through scripting to set a button to start at its highlighted color state rather than it's normal color state? I have two buttons that select two different custom keypads and I want one of them to be automatically selected on start, therefore I'd like the button associated with that keypad to be already selected (in the highlighted state). Any way to do this?

Comment: Show your code example. But I think you are looking for the `Focus` method for a button. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it by changing your main color through script.

You can create a ToggleButton, add an Image component and then you get your Toggle component via script :

`Toggle myToggleButton = GameObject.Find("MyButtonName").GetComponent<Toggle>();`

Then you add a script to your button :

`myToggleButton.onValueChanged.AddListener(MyButtonAction);`

And your MyButtonAction() method can look like this :

`void MyButtonAction(bool state){
    if(state)
        toggle.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.green;
    else
        toggle.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.ref;
}`

Or if you don't want to add an Image component to your toggle, you can play with the `myToggleButton.colors`

By the way, you can choose the initial state of a toggle button, so the highlighted color can be the default one if the toggle state is true by default.